# {% for blog in blogs.all %} is printed on html page

Tags: django, html, css

[coding-part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6v0s.png)

This is the part of code when I run it. I am getting {% for blog in blogs.all %} printed on html page. What should I do?
At least suggest what should I do to prevent it from displaying on html page [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBBJU.png)

I tried Writing the entire code again and seeing if those are in h tags but nothing could solve it.

What I want to see [Expectaion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOIPa.png)

But when i use that code again for blog i get [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ToQ.png)
coding part for that correct page was [Code part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmRd5.png)

Comment: There is absolutely no way to help you as you have not shown why of your code, described your setup, or explained how you accessed the page.

Comment: I m actually creating website portfolio using Django framework for the HTML part I used bootstrap I want to create blog webpage in it whereas whenever i run it i get that  {% for blog in blogs.all %} is printed on html page

Comment: That didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: How can i prevent %% from showing on webpage

Comment: I am actually new to stackoverflow so i actually cant explain it properly also to the programming

Answer (score -1):

I presume somewhere in your views.py you did :

```
job = Jobs.get.all()
```

So if you did that, you only need to do in your template

```
{% for job in jobs %}
     {{ job.summary }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps...